# executing "cf-push" using cf-java-client

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-java-client

I am very new to using cloud foundry. Currently, I am trying to automate the task of pushing an app to a target URL using the cloud foundry java client library but I am not being able to figure out how to push the manifest file ,i.e, how do i execute the command "cf push -f " using java client library ?

I am being able to login and view the list of spaces and organizations. I just need to push into an organization in the dev space.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you want to use the [CloudFoundryOperations API](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryoperations-builder). This is a higher level abstraction and mimics the behaviors of the `cf` cli. This is opposed to the [CloudFoundryClient API](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryclient-apis) which more closely mimics the raw underlying Cloud Foundry API.

The [`CloudFoundryOperations.pushManifest(..)` method](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/Applications.html#pushManifest-org.cloudfoundry.operations.applications.PushApplicationManifestRequest-) should do what you want. It takes a [`PushApplicationManifestRequest`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/PushApplicationManifestRequest.html) object.

You can use the [builder directly](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/PushApplicationManifestRequest.Builder.html) to create one, or you can use the [`ApplicationManifestUtils.read(..)` method](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/latest/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/ApplicationManifestUtils.html). The [`read(..)` method](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/ApplicationManifestUtils.html#read-java.nio.file.Path-) will read from a traditional cf cli `manifest.yml` file and you can use the Builder's methods like [`addAllManifests(..)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/PushApplicationManifestRequest.Builder.html#addAllManifests-java.lang.Iterable-) or [`manifests(..)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-operations/4.5.0.RELEASE/org/cloudfoundry/operations/applications/PushApplicationManifestRequest.Builder.html#manifest-org.cloudfoundry.operations.applications.ApplicationManifest-) to add the `ApplicationManifest` object that you get from the call to `read(..)` to your `PushApplicationManifestRequest` object.

When you have the `PushApplicationManifestRequest` object build the way you want, you simply pass that through to `CloudFoundryOperations.pushManifest(..)`.

For other's reference, there is a `CloudFoundryOperations.push(..)` method, if you don't want to use a manifest that one will work too. It functions roughly the same, but doesn't have the support for manifests.